# Automated import in GIMP

Tags: python, python-2.7, gimp

`RUN_INTERACTIVE` gives a dialog with width, height, etc...  How do you automate GIMP to pass these parameters?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gimpfu import *
def dialog( pages ):
  try:
    img  = pdb.file_pdf_load(pages, pages, run_mode = RUN_INTERACTIVE )
  except CancelError:
    return
register( "pdf",  "Import PDF",  "Import PDF",
          "Sketch",  "Sketch",  "2018",
          "<Toolbox>/Import/Import PDF...",  "",
          [  (PF_FILE, "pages", "PDF", "")],
          [],  dialog )
main()
```

Which gives you an interactive dialog.
But I'd like to automate this.
Once I change it to `RUN_NONINTERACTIVE`

```
line 6, in dialog
    run_mode = RUN_NONINTERACTIVE )
RuntimeError: calling error
```

I'd even be fine with an open dialog box,
so long as I could use the script to populate parameters,
but I don't know where you pass those along.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things, the plugin, and the API to the plugin. Usually the API covers the same parameters as the dialog version, but there are exceptions. `file_pdf_load` is among them.

All functions in the PDB can be found with `Filters>Python-fu>Console` and hitting the `Browse...` button. The API descriptions there (including parameters) are created from the plugin registration data, so there is no secret API...

Comment: I've already been there.  `file_pdf_load` doesn't show the dialog parameters, it shows `(pages, pages, run_mode = RUN_INTERACTIVE )` which is in the code above.

Comment: Yes, which is why you won't find any additional parameters. If the parameters aren't shown there, they don't exist...

Comment: They have to exist somewhere.  If not through that method, target the dialog box.  It's just another container with variables in it.

Comment: Perhaps to some function inside the plugin, but not to the plugin. If you want these externalized, then Gimp is open source, you can change the plugin to suit you.

Comment: I'm not re-writing GIMP.  I'd sooner write an xdotool script.  The point is to be cross-platform though.